# Does the Canon Rebel T8i support saved custom shooting profiles?

Tags: canon, camera-settings

What I am asking about is what many cameras have a C1 and a C2 that you can set and the camera will remember those settings the next time you return the camera to that mode.

I have not been able to find anything like that in the manual, but at the same time it seems crazy to me for the camera not to have this hidden somewhere it the settings. It has a ton of presets, and I am wondering if there is any way to use those to save custom profiles.

Even if it's not as easy as turning the wheel, if there is somewhere I can pull up saved settings in a menu, it would really help to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know 3 and 4 number models (xxxD and xxxxD, T8i = EOS 850D) do not support custom shooting profiles. If you want to use such option you should switch to 2 or 1 number models (xxD, xD) like 70D, 5D, 1d and so on.

This option is counted as more advanced and reasonably is not available on low end models.

P.S. In [Magic Lantern](https://magiclantern.fm/) there is such [option](https://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=23654.0), [option 2](https://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=24993.0) (to store in scene modes for custom shooting modes) but your camera is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

No. The Canon Rebel T8i/850D does not have the capability to store *Custom* shooting modes like Canon's more advanced models. None of the "Rebel" line (xx00D and xx0D models) offers this feature.